# Mezclar una rama en menos pasos

Tags: git, git-merge

Estoy por fin tratando de aprender a usar git desde consola, pues siempre lo usaba desde plugins por comodidad y realicé el siguiente ejercicio cuyo enunciado dice:

Para completar este nivel, seguí estos pasos:

1. Creá una nueva rama, llamada bugFix
2. Checkouteá la rama bugFix usando git checkout bugFix
3. Hacé un commit
4. Volvé a master con git checkout
5. Hacé otro commit
6. Mergeá la rama bugFix a master usando git merge

El estado inical es

[image: inicial]

Y se debe llegar a esta solución:

[image: Objetivo]

## Intentos

```
$ git branch bugFix
$ git checkout bugFix
$ git commit
$ git checkout master
$ git commit
$ git merge bugFix
```

Sin embago me aparece un mensaje que dice:

> Resolviste el nivel en 6 comandos; nuestra mejor solución usa 5.
>
> Fijate si podés bajarlo a usar sólo 5 comandos :D

Considero que todos los comandos de mi solución son necesarios y que debería de haber una forma de combinar dos de ellos pero no se me ocurre como. ¿Cómo puedo reducir el número de pasos para resolver este problema?

Comment: @Trauma funcionó! Por favor agrega tu respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes reducir los dos primeros pasos usando la opción -b del comando checkout, que crea la rama y después hace checkout sobre ella.

```
$ git checkout -b bugFix
$ git commit
$ git checkout master
$ git commit
$ git merge bugFix
```